# python: cleaning up a string

Tags: python, string

i have a string like this

```
somestring='in this/ string / i have many. interesting.occurrences of {different chars} that need     to .be removed  '
```

here is the result i want:

```
somestring='in this string i have many interesting occurrences of different chars that need to be removed'
```

i started to manually do all kinds of `.replace`, but there are so many different combinations that i think there must be a simpler way. perhaps there's a library that already does this?

does anyone know how i can clean up this string>?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I would use regular expression to replace all non-alphanumerics to spaces:

```
>>> import re
>>> somestring='in this/ string / i have many. interesting.occurrences of {different chars} that need     to .be removed  '
>>> rx = re.compile('\W+')
>>> res = rx.sub(' ', somestring).strip()
>>> res
'in this string i have many interesting occurrences of different chars that need to be removed'
```

Comment: wowowow!! this is pretty amazing!! where can i read about this library?

Comment: @user: That is just a simple regular expression. The library is in http://docs.python.org/library/re.html. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/ for more about regex.

Answer (score 2):

You have two steps: remove the punctuation then remove the extra whitespace.

1) Use string.translate

```
import string
trans_table = string.maketrans( string.punctuation, " "*len(string.punctuation)
new_string = some_string.translate(trans_table)
```

This makes then applies a translation table that maps punctuation characters to whitespace.

2) Remove excess whitespace

```
new_string = " ".join(new_string.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
re.sub('[\[\]/{}.,]+', '', somestring)
```

Comment: Note that `interesting.occurrences` needs to become `interesting occurrences` with a space.

Comment: And multiple spaces `'need      to'` condensed to one `'need to'`